# I just earned a New Year's hat on Dec 8

Tags: bug, winter-bash, winter-bash-2019

I have a new hat... but it's not clear why. And the description needs some help

> post a message in chat within ±12 hours of the UTC New Year’s begin that gets starred

"New Year's begin"? Did you mean

> within ±12 hours of the start of UTC New Year’s Day

And it's Dec 8 to boot. I think we're well outside 12 hours of UTC New Year's

Comment: I live in Murica. We live in the past and you can't make us stop!

Comment: Happy new year than ;)

Comment: Where I live is also behind the times, and nobody will ever make us catch up! :D

Comment: My humble votes don't count, but this does not seem to be a dup of the linked question. Changing years and out-of-bounds timing are not remotely connected.